# neo4j query with filter (contains)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i made a query with NEO4j that works fine and quickly **without** filter (Contains + OR/AND conditions) , but when i added the filter the query is stuck and not responding.
Without the filter there is +- 70,000 results
Query example below:

```
MATCH (movie: movie) WHERE  (movie.movie="xxx_xxxx" )
with movie
MATCH (movie)-[found:found]->(n:firstName)
with n, movie
MATCH (n)-[:cinema|secondName*0..1]->(g)-[p:cinema]->(cinema:cinema)<-[found:found]-(movie)
with n,g,cinema,movie
OPTIONAL MATCH (cinema)-[as:ID]->(id:ID)<-[found:found]-(movie)
with n,g,cinema,id,movie
OPTIONAL MATCH (id:ID)-[p2:cinema]->(cinema2:cinema)<-[found:found]-(movie)
with n,g,cinema,id,cinema2
OPTIONAL MATCH path2 = ((cinema:cinema)-[as:ID]->(id:ID)-[p2:cinema]->(cinema2:cinema))
with path2,n,g,id,cinema,cinema2
MATCH path = (n)-[:cinema|secondName*0..1]->(g)-[p:cinema]->(cinema:cinema)
with n,cinema,path,path2
WHERE
(  (  toLower(n.nickname) CONTAINS toLower("jhon") OR
 toLower(g.nickname) CONTAINS toLower("jhon") OR
 toLower(cinema.address) CONTAINS toLower("jhon")
)   )
return DISTINCT NODES(path)+COALESCE (NODES(path2),[]), RELATIONSHIPS(path)+COALESCE (RELATIONSHIPS(path2),[])
SKIP 0 LIMIT 5
```

Do you have any idea why the filter stuck the query?

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause requires `g`, but the preceding `WITH` clause does not pass it. It seems the Cypher planner does not flag this as an error (at least in 4.1.0), but it is possible that it could cause an issue. So, try changing `with n,cinema,path,path2` to `with n,cinema,path,path2,g`.

By the way, your `WHERE` clause can made a bit more efficient, since there is no need to call `TOLOWER("jhon")` (up to 3 times) when you could just use "jhon" as-is. So, you should changed this:

```
WHERE
(  (  toLower(n.nickname) CONTAINS toLower("jhon") OR
 toLower(g.nickname) CONTAINS toLower("jhon") OR
 toLower(cinema.address) CONTAINS toLower("jhon")
)   )
```

to this:

```
WHERE
 toLower(n.nickname) CONTAINS "jhon" OR
 toLower(g.nickname) CONTAINS "jhon" OR
 toLower(cinema.address) CONTAINS "jhon"
```